# Are all $v \in \Lambda ^k V$ decomposable if $k > \frac{1}{2} \dim V$?

Tags: tensor-products, multilinear-algebra, exterior-algebra, tensor-decomposition

**Update:**
It seems I proved only the $(\dim S)$-decomposibility of the sum of two decomposables, since $s_1 + s_2$ *is not* decomposable (which I'm not quite sure of).

---

**Original post:**

Let $V$ be any $n$-dimensional real vector space and $\Lambda^k V$ be its $k$-th exterior power. Then I have this little conjecture about decomposability of $v \in \Lambda^k V$,

> If $k > n/2 = \dim V/2$ then every (nonzero) $v \in \Lambda^k V$ is decomposable, i.e. can be written as a single product $v = v_1\wedge \dots \wedge v_k$ for some linearly independent vectors $v_1,\dots, v_k \in V$.

The motivation for that is that in $\mathbb R^3$ any 2-dimensional subspaces have a nontrivial intersection. That allows to rewrite each term in a sum $u_1\wedge u_2 + w_1\wedge w_2 = x\wedge (u_2 + w_2)$ for some $x \in S = U \cap W$, where $U = span\{u_1,u_2\}$, $W=span\{w_1,w_2\}$

In higher dimesnional spaces any subspaces whose dimension $k > n/2$ will necessarily intersect in a nontrivial subspace of dimension $\ge 2k - n > 0$. Recall that a decomposable $k$-vector corresponds to $k$-dimensional subspace. So any sum of two (and more) $k$-vectors $u,w$ will have there corresponding subspaces $U,W$ intersecting if $k > n/2$. In that subspace one can find a common $x \in \Lambda^{\dim S} V$ so that $ u + w = x \wedge s$, where $s \in \Lambda^{k-\dim S} V$.

---

**Added:**

The proof could be sketched as follows: each of the two decomposable $k$-vectors $u,w$ can be written as wedge of $k$ linearly independent vectors. Then intersection $S$ is a nontrivial subspace whose basis can be chosen as commen to both $u$ and $w$. Then $u = x\wedge s_1$ and $w = x \wedge s_2$ and $u + w = x \wedge (s_1 + s_2)$, where $x \in \Lambda^{\dim S} V$ and $s_1,s_2 \in \Lambda^{k - \dim S} V$.

Comment: It's not clear that $s_1 + s_2$ is decomposable. That could be the flaw. However, it will work (!) in the case $\bigwedge^{n-1}(V)$. The idea is sound.

Comment: I understand what you mean. It *is* required that $s_1 + s_2$ is decomposable

Comment: Sorry for the deletion. I think what I proved is the $(2k-n)$-decomposibility. i.e. there are *at least* $2k-n$ vectors $x_1,...,x_{\dim{S}} \in V$ such that $w = x\wedge s$

Comment: With your method you can show that every $v \in \bigwedge^{n-1} (V)$ is decomposable ( fully). Otherwise, the sum (of two things) will be only partially decomposable. Still, a good idea!

Comment: Every $v$ has a "kernel" ( the decomposable that divides it)

Answer (score 1):

What is known: if $n = \dim V$, then every $v \in \bigwedge^{n-1} V$ is decomposable.

Let's test your result on the case $n= 5$. Your claim is that every $v$ in $\bigwedge ^{3} V$ is decomposable.

Now, let's try to recall the Plucker relations in this case. They will be quadratic relations satisfied by $3\times 3$ minors of a $3\times 5$ matrix.  First, for any $4$ columns of such a matrix we have (Cramer)

$$(1 2 3) 4 = (4 2 3)1+(143)2+(124)3$$

Now, add two more columns to get relations between minors. For instance

$$(123)(4 15)= (423)(115)+(143)(215)+(124)(315)$$
or
$$(123)(145)+(134)(125)+(124)(135)=0$$
which is coming from an "old relation" for $\wedge^2(k^4)$. Nevertheless, it is a non-trivial relation.

It seems your conjecture is not true here.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what Plucker relations are. But if you give an explicit example in the ordinary notation then I could understand your idea. Also I added some idea of the proof of my conjecture. Could you check where the flaw is. Thanks

Comment: By $(ijk)$ we denote the coefficient $c_{ijk}$ of a (decomposable) vector $v \in \bigwedge^{3}(V)$. Writing in this way is discouraged nowadays... until you see how convenient it is. Leibniz would write $12$ for the entry $a_{12}$ in a matrix...